# CSS showing and hiding childs and parents

Tags: html, css

I have 3 levels of lists. I want just that li's options box to show. Not any child's options and not any parent's options box. Currently when I walk down the tree, the parent stays hovered which makes sense but is not what I want. How do I do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/tGQUa/3/

HTML

```
<ul class="firstLevel">
<li>
    <label>Test 1</label>
    <div class="options">
        <a href="">Delete</a>
        <a href="">Add</a>
    </div>

    <ul class="secondLevel">
        <li>
            <label>Test 2</label>
            <div class="options">
                <a href="">Delete</a>
                <a href="">Add</a>
            </div>

            <ul class="thirdLevel">
                <li>
                    <label>Test 3</label>
                    <div class="options">
                        <a href="">Delete</a>
                        <a href="">Add</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

​

CSS

```
ul.secondLevel {margin-left:15px;}
ul.thirdLevel {margin-left:15px;}

ul.firstLevel li .options{
    display: none;
}
ul.firstLevel li:first-child:hover > .options{
    display: inline-block;
}
ul.secondLevel li .options{
   display: none;
}
ul.secondLevel li:first-child:hover > .options{
    display: inline-block;
}
ul.thirdLevel li .options{
    display: none;
}
ul.thirdLevel li:first-child:hover > .options{
    display: inline-block;
}

.options {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try the "next sibling" `+` selector?

```
.options { display: none }

.options:hover,
label:hover + .options { display: inline-block }
```

And with some pseudo element trickery and clever positioning, you can achieve a pure CSS solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/tGQUa/10/

Comment: That is awesome. I never knew about the + sign in css. That is actually all I needed and simplified your solution trying to figure out how that worked.  http://jsfiddle.net/tGQUa/12/  Thanks

Comment: @Boone - Cool, wanna accept the answer if it helped solve your problem :)